# Regular Expressions Quantifier OR

Tags: regex

I am simply looking how to detect and odd or even amount (quantifier), or a certain amount (not a range) of a character in a text file.
For example this regular expression detects an odd digit:

```
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

This regular expression detects an amount (1 through 9) of digits:

```
\d{1,9}
```

I would like to find an odd *amount* of digits.

```
\d{1|3|5|7|9}
```

However this syntax is not the right one. Could anyone give me the right answer?

Answer (score 3):

You could use grouping with a word boundary to find one digit followed by any number of two consecutive digits:

```
\b\d(\d\d)*\b
```

Here's an example: http://rubular.com/r/vLTJSJIOJh

Comment: You might wanna convert it to non-capturing group [`\b\d(?:\d\d)*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/eU8rK8/2).

Answer (score 1):

you can use lookahead and lookbehind and 2n+1 pattern

```
(?<!\d)(?:\d\d)*\d(?!\d)
```

`(?<!REGEX)` match negative ahead, `(?!REGEX)` match negative behind, `(?:)` make it non capture.

tests: http://rubular.com/r/RhTtKq9m9O

---

1. [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)